# Seq2Seq : facing shape related issues while training (runnable code included)

Tags: python, tensorflow

Trying to create a seq2seq(tensorflow lib) which takes in various forms of date types and converts them to a general form. It generates data itself so you can just run it on your system.

Not sure what else is there to add. If you are familiar with tf.seq2seq , you would find this code pretty straightforward.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
    import random
import babel
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from babel.dates import format_date
from faker import Faker
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import faiss

fake = Faker()
fake.seed(42)
random.seed(42)

END_SYMBOL = '<END>'

FORMATS = ['short',
           'medium',
           'long',
           'full',
           'd MMM YYY',
           'd MMMM YYY',
           'dd MMM YYY',
           'd MMM, YYY',
           'd MMMM, YYY',
           'dd, MMM YYY',
           'd MM YY',
           'd MMMM YYY',
           'MMMM d YYY',
           'MMMM d, YYY',
           'dd.MM.YY',
           ]

LOCALES = babel.localedata.locale_identifiers()
LOCALES = [lang for lang in LOCALES if 'en' in str(lang)]

def create_date():
    dt = fake.date_object()
    try:
        human = format_date(dt,
                            format=random.choice(FORMATS),
                            locale=random.choice(LOCALES))

        case_change = random.randint(0, 3)  # 1/2 chance of case change
        if case_change == 1:
            human = human.upper()
        elif case_change == 2:
            human = human.lower()

        machine = dt.isoformat()
    except AttributeError as e:
        return None, None, None

    return human, machine  # , dt


# Date data
data = [create_date() for _ in range(50000)]
x = [x for x, y in data]
y = [y for x, y in data]

# BABI dialog
# query, response = generate_data(file_path)
# x = ''.join(str(query))
# y= ''.join(str(response))

u_characters = set(' '.join(x))
char2numX = dict(zip(u_characters, range(len(u_characters))))

u_characters = set(' '.join(y))
char2numY = dict(zip(u_characters, range(len(u_characters))))

char2numX['<PAD>'] = len(char2numX)
num2charX = dict(zip(char2numX.values(), char2numX.keys()))
max_len = max([len(date) for date in x])

x = [[char2numX['<PAD>']] * (max_len - len(date)) + [char2numX[x_] for x_ in date] for date in x]
print(''.join([num2charX[x_] for x_ in x[4]]))
x = np.array(x)

char2numY['<GO>'] = len(char2numY)
num2charY = dict(zip(char2numY.values(), char2numY.keys()))

y = [[char2numY['<GO>']] + [char2numY[y_] for y_ in date] for date in y]
print(''.join([num2charY[y_] for y_ in y[4]]))

y = np.array(y)

x_seq_length = len(x[0])
y_seq_length = len(y[0]) - 1
t = 0

y.flatten()

def batch_data(x, y, batch_size):
    start = 0

    while start + batch_size <= len(x):
        yield x[start:start + batch_size], y[start:start + batch_size]
        start += batch_size
########################################################################################################################
epochs = 10
batch_size = 128
nodes = 32
embed_size = 10

tf.reset_default_graph()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (None, None), 'inputs')
outputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (None, None), 'output')
targets = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (None, None), 'targets')
target_seq_len = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=(batch_size), name='seq_len')

# Embedding layers
input_embedding = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform((len(char2numX), embed_size), -1.0, 1.0), name='enc_embedding')
output_embedding = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform((len(char2numY), embed_size), -1.0, 1.0), name='dec_embedding')
date_input_embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(input_embedding, inputs)
date_output_embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(output_embedding, outputs)

seqlen = tf.constant(x_seq_length,shape=[x_seq_length])
########################################################################################################################

with tf.variable_scope("encoding") as encoding_scope:
    lstm_enc = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(nodes)
    encoder_output, last_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_enc, inputs=date_input_embed, dtype=tf.float32)

    print("\n\n last state", last_state)

with tf.variable_scope("decoding") as decoding_scope:
    lstm_dec = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(nodes)
    # dec_outputs, dec_states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_dec, inputs=date_output_embed, initial_state=last_state)

############################################################################################################################################
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

# Train
############################################################################################################################################
# Train Helper
train_helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.TrainingHelper(inputs=input_embedding,
                                                 sequence_length=seqlen,
                                                 time_major=True)
# decoder
train_decoder = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(cell=lstm_dec, helper=train_helper, initial_state=last_state)
# outputs
dec_outputs, _, _ = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(decoder=train_decoder, maximum_iterations=20)
rnn_out, sample_ids = dec_outputs
##############################################################################
with tf.name_scope("optimizer"):
    loss = tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss(rnn_out, targets, tf.ones([batch_size, y_seq_length]))
    optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(1e-3).minimize(loss)

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for epoch_i in range(epochs):
    for batch_i, (source_batch, target_batch) in enumerate(batch_data(X_train, y_train, batch_size)):


        batch_logits = sess.run(rnn_out, feed_dict={inputs: source_batch,
                                                    outputs: target_batch[:, :-1],
                                                    targets: target_batch[:, 1:]
                                                    })#target_seq_len: np.ones((batch_size), dtype=int) * x_seq_length

        print("\n logits:", batch_logits)
############################################################################################################################################

############################################################################################################################################
# Test

# Batches
source_batch, target_batch = next(batch_data(X_test, y_test, batch_size))

# Inference Helper
inference_helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.GreedyEmbeddingHelper(embedding=output_embedding,
                                                            start_tokens=tf.fill([batch_size], 0), end_token=1)

# decoder
decoder = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(cell=lstm_dec, helper=inference_helper,
                                          initial_state=last_state)

# outputs
predicted_outputs, predicted_states, _ = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(decoder=decoder, maximum_iterations=20)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what issues you're seeing; stack traces, etc?

Comment: I dont think the model is training. I do get the logits but I get them instantaneously.  you may just copy paste it on your system and run it